# How to enable Redis extension for XAMPP in Ubuntu environment.

Tags: php, ubuntu, redis, xampp

I found the following url for PHP client.

http://anton.logvinenko.name/en/blog/how-to-install-redis-and-redis-php-client.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this at your end : https://gist.github.com/Sidereal/3953563.
If Redis server is already installed skip that step and simply install   compatible version of redis client and update your php.ini accordingly.